# PeriodicWorkRequest with WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Well as WorkManager is newly introduce in Google I/O, I'm trying to use workmanager to perform task periodically,

What I'm doing is, Scheduling the work using `PeriodicWorkRequest` as following :

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build();
PeriodicWorkRequest build = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(SyncJobWorker.class, MY_SCHEDULE_TIME, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
           .addTag(TAG)
           .setConstraints(constraints)
           .build();

WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance();
if (instance != null) {
          instance.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, build);
}
```

Problem I'm having is when i'm requesting `PeriodicWorkRequest` then also it will start work immediately,

- **Does anybody know how to stop that immediate work execution? while using PeriodicWorkRequest.**
- Also want to know how we can Rechedule the work? **What if i want to change the time of already scheduled work ?**

I'm using : `implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha04"`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you find the solution to set initial delay to PeriodicWorkRequest?

Comment: Actually I have not tried latest version of work manager so don't have any idea.

Comment: I tried in latest alpha version w/o any luck.

Comment: Will update if I found solution

Answer (score 20):

You can achieve this by using flex period in [PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder).
As example, if you want run your Worker within 15 minutes at the end of repeat interval (let's say 8 hours), code will look like this:

```
val periodicRefreshRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            RefreshWorker::class.java, // Your worker class
            8, // repeating interval
            TimeUnit.HOURS,
            15, // flex interval - worker will run somewhen within this period of time, but at the end of repeating interval
            TimeUnit.MINUTES
    )
```

[Visual ilustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuN4f.png)

Answer (score 4):

you need to add *initialDelay* to the builder

```
fun scheduleRecurringFetchWeatherSyncUsingWorker() {
    val constraints: Constraints = Constraints.Builder().apply {
        setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
    }.build()

    val request: PeriodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
        MySimpleWorker::class.java, 3, TimeUnit.HOURS, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .setInitialDelay(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .build()
    mWorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        TAG_WORK_NAME,
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
        request
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks, the initial delay was not there earlier in alpha version.

Answer (score 0):

Your code always reschedule the work, so you could change the work parameters as you want

```
instance.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, build);
```

if you want to keep the work with same parameters (even after reboot), without any changes, use:

```
instance.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, build);
```

in the case it will be scheduled it only if the work is not engueued already.

For to stop the work task, use

```
// cancel the unique work
instance.cancelUniqueWork(TAG);
// clear all finished or cancelled tasks from the WorkManager 
instance.pruneWork();
```

Btw, I think its not good approach to use same TAG as the unigue work id and as task tag. In case you need unique work - you dont really need the task tag at all. The task tag is for cases then you want to have several tasks

Comment: @UttamPanchasara whats exactly not work? I use it with ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP in OnCreate() for my Application object and with ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE then I change settings for the task (like scheduling it with different interval). For me it works very well. I also tried instance.wm.cancelUniqueWork(TAG) and for me it works. Btw, I use "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha10"

Comment: Policy way that you explained was not working with me,, and I have not tried with latest work manager version

Answer (score 0):

You can delay your task using `setInitialDelay`. This works for both `OneTimeWorkRequest` and `PeriodicWorkRequest` .

```html
val myWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWork>()
   .setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .build()
```

In case of `PeriodicWorkRequest` only the first run of your periodic work would be delayed.

Answer (score -1):

To delay the task you could use setInitialDelay.

> We have used setInitialDelay to ensure the notification is triggered
>   on the day of the event rather than immediately. This delay is
>   calculated by a separate method which returns the amount of
>   milliseconds between now and when the notification should trigger (at
>   noon on the date of the event). Please note that this delay is not
>   always accurate! Due to how modern Android works, your work can be
>   delayed by a number of factors, so be aware of this for very time
>   sensitive purposes.

All the info is in this post. https://medium.com/@eydryan/scheduling-notifications-on-android-with-workmanager-6d84b7f64613

Comment: setInitialDelay will only work with oneTimeRequest I'm scheduling with periodic work request.

Comment: @UttamPanchasara Initial delay is now supported for `PeriodicWorkRequest` (see [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.1.0-alpha02))

Comment: Thanks for the update @Valim, this feature isl really helpful.