# Android Kotlin Service issue

Tags: android, kotlin

I have implemented a service that runs in the background of the application. The service calls the function every minute, which checks if the time has come to trigger the notification - reminder (retrieves the current date and time and compares it with the data saved in the database. If the date and time match, the notification is triggered. The function is called every 1 minute. Function this one must check every 1 minute the condition when the user uses the application, the application runs in the background, does not use the application and how the phone is asleep. By implementing reminders the previous day evening to the evening and the next day. Reminders appear for the same day for the evening and the first reminder for the next day. The next ones do not appear. On the other hand, the reminder set for 5 minutes works and for 30 no longer. Looking for information I found on the internet that the problem lies in:

- time drift - When the screen is on and the phone is fully awake, the interval between two consecutive events will remain constant most of the time, but may jump from time to time (lengthen)
- the phone goes into sleep mode

Any of you have an idea how to solve this, get around it?

*ForegroundService*

```
class ForegroundService : Service() {
    companion object {
        val CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel"
        val CHANNEL_ID_CHILD = "ForegroundServiceChannelCHILD"
        private var isRunning = true
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val input = intent.getIntExtra("time",15)
        createNotificationChannel()
        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, Menu::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0
        )

        val wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock =
            (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
                newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::AR_Apteczka").apply {
                    acquire()
                }
            }



        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Twoja Elektroniczna Apteczka")
            .setContentText("Dbamy o Twoje zdrowie")
            .setSmallIcon(com.example.agnieszka.ar_apteczka.R.drawable.pills)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            //.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            //.setSound(null)
            .build()



        startForeground(1, notification)
        isRunning = true
        val context = this
        val intent = Intent(this, ShowAllTodaysMedicines::class.java)
        val pendingIntentNotification = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        doAsync {
            while(true)
            {
                var message= createReminderMessage(context)

                uiThread {
                        if(true) {
                            if (message != "Nadszedł czas by zażyć: ") {
                                val notification =
                                    NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID_CHILD)
                                        .setContentTitle("Zażyj leki")
                                        .setContentText(message)
                                        .setSmallIcon(com.example.agnieszka.ar_apteczka.R.drawable.pills)
                                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntentNotification)
                                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                                        .build()
                                with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
                                    notificationManager.notify(2, notification)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }

                //SystemClock.sleep(60000)
                SystemClock.sleep(60*1000-SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()%1000)
               // SystemClock.sleep(50000) //10*1000-SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()%1000
            }
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        isRunning = false
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                //NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            //serviceChannel.setSound(null, null) //
            val serviceChannel2 = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID_CHILD,
                "Foreground Service ChannelChild ",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                //NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            )
            val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel2)
        }
    }

    fun reminderForNow(context: Context) : ArrayList<Reminder> {
        var listOfReminder : ArrayList<Reminder> = ArrayList()
        var timetoday = takeTimeNow()
        var dateToday = takeTodayDate()

        val dbHelper = SQLConector(context)
        val allRemindersList = dbHelper.getAllReminders()
        for (i: Reminder in allRemindersList) {

            if (i.reminderDate == dateToday && i.ReminderTime == timetoday) {
                var reminder = Reminder(
                    i.idReminder,
                    i.medicineName,
                    i.reminderDate,
                    i.ReminderTime
                )
                listOfReminder.add(reminder)
            }
        }
        return listOfReminder
    }

    private fun createReminderMessage(p0: Context) : String{
        var message = "Nadszedł czas by zażyć: "
        var listOfReminders = reminderForNow(p0)
        if(listOfReminders.count() > 0){
            for (i: Reminder in listOfReminders) {
                message += i.medicineName + ", "
            }
        }
        return message
    }

 private fun takeTodayDate():String{
        val current = LocalDateTime.now()
        val formatDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
     var currentDate = current.format(formatDate).toString()
        return  currentDate
    }

    private fun takeTimeNow() : String{
        val current = LocalDateTime.now()
        val formatTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")
        return current.format(formatTime).toString()
    }
}


**Main Activity**

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.buttonStart.setOnClickListener { startService() }
        binding.buttonStop.setOnClickListener {stopService()  }
        startService()
    }


    private fun startService() {
        val serviceIntent = Intent(this, ForegroundService::class.java)
        serviceIntent.putExtra("time", 1)

        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent)
    }

    private fun stopService() {
        val serviceIntent = Intent(this, ForegroundService::class.java)
        stopService(serviceIntent)
    }

}

*Manifest*
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<application
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/pills"
            android:label="@string/nameOfApplications"
            android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service
                android:name=".ForegroundService"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Service won't run in the background forever, the what you are looking for is the alarm manager or the workmanager, the dalvik or the ATN machine can kill any process at any time, that inclueds services, and I don't think that service is correct because it has to bind to an activity

Comment: I implemented the Alarm Manager two ways, in which he gives my service, however, debugging the program and testing does not enter my service. Could you say what I'm doing wrong? @cutiko
In each ways the service does not turn on. 
Antoine can tell me if i good understand ifi culd use my Foregriund service in AlarmMananger or not?

Comment: 1 way:
alarmMgr = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmIntent = Intent(this, ForegroundService::class.java).let { intent ->
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)
        }


        alarmMgr?.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
            10 * 60,
            alarmIntent
        )

Comment: 2 way:

fun setOnetimeTimer(context: Context) {
        val am = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
          val intent = Intent(context, ForegroundService::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("time",java.lang.Boolean.TRUE)
    val pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60, pi)

Comment: I already told you, the service needs to be bound to an activity, try using and intent service or as I recommended the workmanager

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PeriodicWorkRequest with WorkManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153003/periodicworkrequest-with-workmanager)

Comment: @cutiko `Service` doesn't have to bind to an `Activity`. As long as it's a foreground service, Android will give it roughly the same priority as an app with an onscreen `Activity`. It is very unlikely to be preemptively terminated. That said, the OP must be advised against trying to solve the problem this way, and it is much better to use `AlarmManager` or `WorkManager` as you suggested.

Comment: @greeble31 services has to be bound to an activity bound services not, the priority of the virtual machine is to make sure the app in foreground is running smooth if anything else is consuming resources it will be killed so "rouughly" takes us back to the beginning

Comment: @cutiko Well, right, the OS can decide to terminate any JVM on the basis of excessive resource usage. But the point is, having a foreground service makes that _much less likely_; it makes the app a "foreground app". Binding the `Service` to an `Activity` does not do that. Have an `Activity` on screen? Yes, you have a "foreground app". But once that `Activity` disappears, you now have a "background app", and it's much more likely to be killed. It doesn't matter if it's bound or not.